# basic structure of com object

Tags: c++, com

What is the basic structure of a com object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A COM object doesn't have any defined structure, beyond the vtable (virtual function pointer table) associated with each of its interfaces.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608924/memory-layout-difference-between-nested-classes-and-multiple-inheritance-in-c/4609422#4609422) which is more or less the same question.

Comment: The vtable is its defined structure!

Comment: Not really - the vtable is associated with an interface: an object may have several, and they can be anywhere in memory.