# What is the VTable's method pointers order if class implements more than 1 interface?

Tags: c++, com, vtable

I know that if class A implements for example IUnknown and IComSomething1, than the VTable's method order will be first IUnknown and than IComSomething1. As far as I know this is always the order because IComSomething1 inherits IUnknown.

But what is the order if class A implements IUnknown and IComSomething1 and IComSomething2 ? What is the order of the VTable method pointer between IComSomething1 and IComSomething2 ?

(The question does not apply only to COM, but it comes out of a COM issue that it calls the function by a vtable offset).

I tried to find some answers "out there" but I couldn't find any straight, clear, answer.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: There is an old article about VC++'s implementation [here](http://www.openrce.org/articles/files/jangrayhood.pdf), I would assume that the basic principles haven't changed (but of course other implementations will be different).

Comment: Why does it matter? vtables are implementation details. The C++ standard has no notion of a vtable.

Comment: @FredOverflow Sadly, COM object interfaces map to their vtable implementation.  It is probably only interesting as a COM question.

Comment: probably the same answer that this question received: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4608924/memory-layout-difference-between-nested-classes-and-multiple-inheritance-in-c

Comment: @FredOverflow it matters to people who like to know how things work underneath. Not for any practical reason (besides reverse engineering, which is very interesting in itself).

Comment: @Jesse - I would mark it as a answer if it wasn't a comment. That article explains my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of vtable members in a class is not well-defined. Indeed, you can (and will!) find data members between vtable pointers. If you're writing COM, you should cast to whatever interface you want to return in your `QueryInterface` prior to writing it to the pointer you're putting the result in. That is, something like:

```
HRESULT QueryInterface(REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppvObject) {
  if (*riid == IID_MY_INTERFACE) {
    *ppvObject = static_cast<IMyInterface *>(this);
    return S_OK;
  } else if (*riid == IID_SOMETHING_ELSE) {
    *ppvObject = static_cast<ISomethingElse *>(this);
    return S_OK;
  } else /* ... */
}
```

The compiler will take care of finding the right offset for the interface for you.

As for how it actually works, think about what this implies - each of the interfaces must exist as an object at some subrange of offsets within the object.. Say you have a class heirarchy that looks like this:

```
class IA { virtual void foo() = 0; int x;};
class IB { virtual void bar() = 0; int y; };
class C : public IA, public IB { int bar; };
```

Your in-memory layout might look like this:

```
00000000 vtable ptr for C
00000004 vtable ptr for Ia
00000008 int x
0000000b vtable ptr for Ib
00000010 int y
00000014 int bar
```

Here you can get a pointer to an Ia by getting an offset `0x00000004` into the class, or Ib at `0x0000000b`.

It may in some cases by possible to optimize this further:

```
00000000 vtable ptr for C and Ia
00000004 int x
00000008 vtable ptr for Ib
0000000b int y
00000010 int bar
```

I'm not sure if the win32 C++ ABI actually does this. If you do do this, then the C vtable starts with the same members as the Ia vtable, then adds on extra ones at the end.

Comment: There's also an intermediate optimization, where the `C` vtable is shared with the `Ia` vtable, but there are two pointers to it. That can be done independently of the ABI and still gives you better locality of reference.

Comment: @MSalters, indeed - you may be able to merge the `B` vtable as well in that manner.